# How to complete this?

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f$ a function defined  on $]0,+\infty[$ and checking  :
$$\forall  x,y>0,\ f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$$ 
Assume that $f$ is bounded on $]1-\eta,1+\eta[$($\subset]0,+\infty[$). Let $\alpha =\underset{x\in ]1,1+\eta[}{\inf}f(x)$ and $\beta =\underset{x\in ]1,1+\eta[}{\sup}f(x)$.
So we have :

- If $\alpha >0$, $f$ is increasing on $]0,+\infty[$2)
- If $\beta <0$, $f$ is decreasing on $]0,+\infty[$
- And if $\alpha <0<\beta$, how falling into a contradiction in this case ???!!!!

Comment: What is your question? (I am not really clear on what you are asking)

Comment: What is the meaning of $]0,+\infty[$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That would be $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: It is not clear?

Comment: $]0,+\infty[=(0,\infty)$ and if $\alpha <0 <\beta$, how to something which is contradictory. Thank you?

Comment: I try to show that f is monotonic.

Comment: @Said No, the question is not clear at all... for instance, nowhere in your question is even written that you are trying to show $f$ is monotone...

Comment: Let $f$ a function defined  on $]0,+\infty[$ and   :
$$\forall  x,y>0,\ f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$$
If $f$ is bounded in the neighborhood of 1,  
I try to show that f is monotone.

Comment: Am I missing something here? We know that $f(1)=0$ since $f(x\cdot 1)=f(x)+f(1)$ so we know that $\alpha\le0$ and $\beta\ge0$.

Comment: I need to show that $f$ is monotone to show that $f$ is convex or concave. If we can show that $f$ is convex or concave without monotony that is better.